# Cypress hover over the menu option called "Automation"

Tags: css, css-selectors, cypress

I am trying to hover over the menu option(shots - it is under automation tab) by using this below command however it does not seem to work:

```
cy.get('.menu.button.overlay_button.projects_popover').click(),
cy.contains('Automation').trigger('mousedown'),
cy.contains('Shots').trigger('mousedown').click()
```

Does cypress have the hover option?

I am click on the projects first, then going to Automation and then click on shots.

[image]

also, i do not think if there is any thing as hover in cypress. I want to place my mouse on that"Automation" tab. I am able to click it but i cannot do hover like selenium. Please help

Comment: There is a missing dot in the second line - but I assume this isn't the solution to your problem O:)

Comment: @andreas, no the i fixed that but that is not the problem

Comment: also, i do not think if there is any thing as hover in cypress. I want to place my mouse on that"Automation". I am able to click it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Cypress does not currently have a `hover()` command. However this will probably be added in the future.

There are two different forms of hover code in the browser:

1) `css` styling via a `:hover` pseudo class
2) `javascript` via `mouseover/mouseout` event listeners.

If your app uses #1(`css`), cypress cannot currently test that because it cannot parse pseudo css styles via javascript.

If your app uses #2(`javascript` events), you can use a workaround, triggering the `mouseover/mouseout` events manually:

```js
cy.get('.menu.button.overlay_button.projects_popover').click(),
cy.contains('Automation').trigger('mouseover'),
cy.contains('Shots').trigger('mouseover').click()
```

There is also a possibility your app is listening to the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events, in which case you can trigger those as well.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases this event is more reliable.

```js
cy.contains('Automation').trigger('mouseenter')
```