# Element not appearing with cypress mouseover

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

The issue is when hovered through cypress it won’t show the element that I am trying to interact with but when actually hovered through the mouse it does. Somehow cypress can’t seem to mimic the actual hover. The solutions I tried are listed below:

1- invoke(‘show’)

2- trigger(‘mousemove’) with different options such as moving to right, providing the client x and client y parameters

3- Passing force true as well

4- trigger(‘mouseover’) with all the above combinations

What I am trying to do is that an element is hidden and is visible when hovered. So, I want to hover and click on that element as it becomes visible.

I would really appreciate help if someone with similar scenario encountered this problem and has some kind of remedy for this issue

Comment: Hi, unfortunately when pseudo-class hover is used in CSS, cypress can not handle it. here is a related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091195/cypress-hover-over-the-menu-option-called-automation
commenting here, so that I will be aware if any solution raised :)

Comment: No solution raised so far :/